# Node.js Promise chain resolving too early

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

There's something about chaining promises that I don't understand. The Node.js snippet below produces the following output. Why is `promise.allSettled` called after the first `sleep` on line 18 and not after the 2nd one on line 21?

```sh
Cycle 0 is going to sleep     promise.js:2
Cycle 0 slept for 2 seconds   promise.js:6
Returned from sleep function  promise.js:19
Cycle 0 is going to sleep     promise.js:2
Done with the process         promise.js:27
Cycle 0 slept for 2 seconds   promise.js:6
```

```js
function sleep(cycle) {
    console.log(`Cycle ${ cycle } is going to sleep`);

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Cycle ${ cycle } slept for 2 seconds`);
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function process() {
    let cycles       = 1;
    let subprocesses = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
        subprocesses.push(
            sleep(i).then(() => {
                console.log('Returned from sleep function');

                sleep(i);
            })
        );
    }

    Promise.allSettled(subprocesses).then(results => {
        console.log('Done with the process');
    });
}

process();
```

Comment: Thanks for doing a Stack Snippet! But next time, please actually try running it before posting. :-) You had the JavaScript code in the HTML box. I've fixed it for you.

Comment: You don't return the inner `sleep(i)`, so it's not part of the promise chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you haven't resolved the promise created `sleep(i).then` to the promise from the second `sleep`, so it doesn't wait for that second operation to finish before settling. You need a `return` in front of the second call:

```js
function sleep(cycle) {
    console.log(`Cycle ${ cycle } is going to sleep`);

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Cycle ${ cycle } slept for 2 seconds`);
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function process() {
    let cycles       = 1;
    let subprocesses = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
        subprocesses.push(
            sleep(i).then(() => {
                console.log('Returned from sleep function');

                return sleep(i); // <============================
            })
        );
    }

    Promise.allSettled(subprocesses).then(results => {
        console.log('Done with the process');
    });
}

process();
```

Here's a version with two cycles, and with the sleep calls more clearly marked:

```js
function sleep(cycle, sub) {
    console.log(`Cycle ${cycle}(${sub}) is going to sleep`);

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Cycle ${cycle}(${sub}) slept for 2 seconds`);
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function process() {
    let cycles       = 2;
    let subprocesses = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
        subprocesses.push(
            sleep(i, "a").then(() => {
                console.log(`Returned from sleep function (${i})`);

                return sleep(i, "b"); // <============================
            })
        );
    }

    Promise.allSettled(subprocesses).then(results => {
        console.log('Done with the process');
    });
}

process();
```

It might be clearer to split that `sleep`, `sleep` serial operation off into its own function, perhaps an `async` function:

```
async function twoSleep(i) {
    await sleep(i, "a");
    console.log(`Returned from sleep function (${i})`);
    await sleep(i, "b");
}

function process() {
    let cycles       = 2;
    let subprocesses = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
        subprocesses.push(twoSleep(i));
    }

    Promise.allSettled(subprocesses).then(results => {
        console.log('Done with the process');
    });
}
```

```js
function sleep(cycle, sub) {
    console.log(`Cycle ${cycle}(${sub}) is going to sleep`);

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Cycle ${cycle}(${sub}) slept for 2 seconds`);
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}

async function twoSleep(i) {
    await sleep(i, "a");
    console.log(`Returned from sleep function (${i})`);
    await sleep(i, "b");
}

function process() {
    let cycles       = 2;
    let subprocesses = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
        subprocesses.push(twoSleep(i));
    }

    Promise.allSettled(subprocesses).then(results => {
        console.log('Done with the process');
    });
}

process();
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that Promise.allSettled runs all promises in parallel, so all of them resolve at the same time. If you want to run them one by one try

```
async function process() {
  const cycles = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
    await sleep(i).then(() => {
      console.log("Returned from sleep function");
      return sleep(i);
    });
  }

  console.log("Done with the process");
}

process();
```

Comment: *"The issue is that Promise.allSettled runs all promises in parallel..."* No, this is a fundamental misunderstanding of promises. `Promise.allSettled` doesn't **run** anything at all, the work is already underway before it's ever called. All it does it *observe* what's happening. Promises don't *do* anything, they're just a means of observing the completion of something (and what that result was).

Comment: The OP seems to want to do "cycles" in parallel, with two steps in each cycle (the two `sleep` calls) in series within the cycle. *(**not** my downvote, this wasn't an unreasonable way to read the question, and the first thing is an easy misconception to pick up)*